# making dataframe ready for bar plot using groupby and agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

Let us say I have this dataframe

```
d = {'group' : ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B') , 
     'T/F': (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

which looks like this

```
 T/F group
0    1     A
1    0     B
2    1     C
3    0     A
4    1     A
5    1     B
```

I want to make a bar plot sorting how many 1s and how many 0s in each group A, B and C. My guess is I need to first group the data in a way which will make it ready for plotting, (please correct me if I am wrong and if there is a much simple way)

What I am doing is this:

```
bardata = df1.groupby('group').agg({'T/F': lambda x: sum(x == 1)})
```

While this works and it counts number of 1s I have (or 0s if I want) but it cannot do both. For example it currently gives

```
      T/F
group     
A        2
B        1
C        1
```

What would be nice to have is another column which gives sum of all false values (adding one more lambda there also does not help because column name is still T/F). I want to use this data to make stacked bar plot so that I can see how many 1s and 0s each group has.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close.  After your `groupby`, select the column of interest (`T/F`) and pass a dictionary to the `agg` function.

```
bardata = df1.groupby('group')['T/F'].agg({'T': lambda x: sum(x == 1), 
                                           'F': lambda x: sum(x == 0)})

>>> bardata
       T  F
group      
A      2  1
B      1  1
C      1  0
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that before posting but it would only print one column. May be I missed something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ahh..I realize what I was doing wring. You have ['T/F'] before the agg function.